# Play-clj screen and entities

Tags: clojure, play-clj

I am new to the play-clj, and I am confused about `[screen entities]` as arguments for all of the functions. I went through the [tutorial](https://github.com/oakes/play-clj/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md), but am still not getting it i think, what these for all of the functions shared arguments are and what are they containing? I know screen is a map (a record more precisely) containing various functions for the main faunction and entitites is a vector containing aspects about the objects in the game.

What kind of values are the entities and screen holding, are they dependent on the functions we define? I would be very thankful if someone could give me some declarations and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the question is quite general, so I'll give a general answer. If you want specific details, feel free to ask.

Although play-clj supports functional game development, the base elements backing it are Java classes; accessed, set up, and modified in an imperative way. That means you will cause a huge amount of side effects using play-clj. And some behaviour may feel out of your hand when you're used to Clojure, but it sure makes some sense.

Despite the name, `screen` contains a custom instance of the complete libGDX engine, that is it wraps Java-objects for sound, graphics, physics, and asset management. It gets **mutated** in an imperative way, by calling commands followed by a bang.
For example`(let [screen (update! screen :world (box-2d))] (...))` will add a 2d physics engine to your game which will exist from that point of time, even after you leave the binding. Its functions may also mutate entities as side effects, like dropping a ball by applying gravity.

All the `entities` on the other hand will get treated as properly as possible by functions like `step!` (**mutating** their states by applying physics if appropriate) or `render!`. They are maps, and their treatment is based on properties. `:body` means, they need physics, `:shape` means they need to be drawn as a primitive, `:x, :y, :width, :height` etc. do what you'd expect, and so on. You can add other properties and work with them as usual.

Functions expecting these two arguments have one thing in common: If you give them a return value, the game uses this return value as `entities`-vector from that point of time. So don't just modify and return  a single entity unless you want to leave the poor bugger on the screen all alone...

Also make sure to read the docs at https://oakes.github.io/play-clj/, they explain a lot.